# google bar charts Y axis customization

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I want to remove y-axis values, I just want 0 and 1 once, but there are multiple 1's.

"gridlines: { count: 2}, " is not applying. Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chart is using numbers for the y-axis that have decimal places,
which obviously aren't shown due to the number format

would need to see code, options used on the chart, etc. to understand why

also, drawing the chart before it's container is visible can cause problems

however, the chart in the image appears to be a *Material* chart

unfortunately, many of the options you could use to correct the issue
are not supported by *Material* charts, including...

`{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.gridlines.count`

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

recommend using *Core* chart instead, with following option...

`theme: 'material'`

using `ticks` will guarantee which labels appear...

```
vAxis: {
  ticks: [0, 1]
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Category', 'Count'],
    ['Customers Added', 1.4],
    ['Posts Created', null],
    ['Cash Transaction', null],
    ['Card Transaction', null],
    ['Buy Incomplete', null],
    ['Merchant SignUp', null]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chartCol = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chartCol.draw(data, {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [0, 1]
    },
    height: 400,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Agent Report'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

note:

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Core* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , Now i changed to "core" .. Its working fine..

Comment: var options = {
          vAxis: { 
            format: '#',  
            gridlines: { count: 2},
          },
          
          chart: {
            title: 'Agent Report',
            subtitle: "Date: " + selecteddate
          }

         };